# How to prevent an out of bandwidth quota error message in Azure File Storage connector?

Tags: azure, file, azure-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App that uses an Azure File Storage connector to get an image file stored from a File Shares storage account.

As you can see in the raw inputs of the file storage connector, the API connection for the host the queries and the method to get the image file.

```
{
    "method": "get",
    "queries": {
        "inferContentType": "True",
        "path"web imagesages/Product Shots/Giovanni/Wide/xxxxx_gt_WAX_57g.jpg",
        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": "True"
    },
    "path": "/datasets/default/GetFileContentByPath",
    "host": {
        "connection": {
            "name": "/subscriptions/xxxxxcxx-xxxx-xxx-xxa-xxxxxxxxxxxa/resourceGroups/aaaaa-integration-xx-xxxxx-prod/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azurefile"
        }
    }
}
```

Then, the outputs are below.

```
{
    "statusCode": 403,
    "headers": {
        "Retry-After": "109",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, POST",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Max-Age": "3600",
        "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "*",
        "Date": "Mon, 30 Oct 2023 03:28:11 GMT",
        "Content-Length": "98",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
        "statusCode": 403,
        "message": "**Out of bandwidth quota. Quota will be replenished in 00:01:49**."
    }
}
```

The response throws a forbidden 403 error with the message out of bandwidth quota.

I did some research and found the documentation of [Azure File Storage](https://stackoverflow.com), in the general limits section, it says Bandwidth time interval (in milliseconds) with a value of 60000 - which is equivalent to 60 seconds.  I'm confused about the message error that was thrown in the Azure File Storage connector, does it refer to the general limit of bandwidth time interval?

Aside from that, how can I prevent the out-of-bandwith quota error from happening again?

By the way, the SKU tier of the Storage account that is provisioned for the File Share is Standard with replication of RA-GRS and an account kind of Storage V2.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

The screenshot below of the actual Azure File Storage connector.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Aside from that, how can I prevent the out-of-bandwidth quota error from happening again?

You can perform below steps to avoid `out of bandwidth quota` error.

1. If you are using ***recurrence*** trigger in your logic app, then the requests will be frequent and eventually throttling limit will get exceeded. So either you can increase the recurrence interval to 10-15min or you can use ***When a HTTP request is received*** trigger.
2. You can also consider upgrading the storage account tier.

*I have created a new V2 storage account with ***Standard*** tier to get the file content from a file storage using logic app as shown below-*

[image]

***Getting the expected output***-

[image]

Please try to create a new storage account and follow my way, you will get the result too. If your issue still persists, I would suggest you to check with the Product Team.

Comment: thanks for that.  I'll look into the recurrence interval.  And, yes I'm using  When a HTTP request is received trigger.  My last option would be to upgrade the storage account tier to premium but this will entail cost.

Comment: @Junius If you are using the same storage account for multiple purpose then you can consider upgrading it